# Google Maps API - Map misplaced on frame

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

Link: http://www.bastosviegas.com/mapa (please roll over "interactivo" to see the google map)

As you can see the map is not centered in the correct coordinates and it bugs until you maximize/minimize the page.

Anyone ran into this bug yet? If so how did you got it right?

Comment: There is no Google Maps on the URL you posted. I don't speak Italian at all, should I enter something in the input boxes? Also 'interactivo' does nothing (Chrome 16)

Comment: Sorry I was just now messing with it. It should be there now. And it's portuguese, but yes you have to go over "interactivo" to see the google map. I'll mention it in the OP.

Comment: What is the javascript code that inits the map? What is the javascript code that shows it during the mouseover / interactivo hover?

Comment: Maybe the map doesn't assume the correct dimensions because it's not visible? If you delay the initialization (until map_canvas is visible) of the map does it work as expected? I have encountered this before, but that was when resizing the viewport-div. If you resize it you must let Google Maps know else it doesn't know where the center is or how many _tiles_ to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug, anytime you manipulate the div that contains the map you should trigger a map resize with this trigger: `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`

I would add this trigger to the mouseover event.

Here is an example:

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(38.713107, -90.42984);
    var options = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: centerPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], options);

    //when map is shown, trigger resize
    $('#hoverbtn').hover(function(){
       $('#map').show(); 
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    });

}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/bCVgh/) of the above code